# Indentation error: unindent doesnot match outer loop (in an if else statement )

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python programming so please help out.

This is my code;

```
emails=['me@gmail.com','you@hotmail.com','they@gmail.com']

for item in emails:
    if 'us' in item:
      print(item)
    else:
        print('nil')
```

i keep getting this error;

```
File ".\loop.py", line 6
else:
    ^ 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you pasted here...

Comment: @Chris That doesn't cause any problem, separate, independant blocks can be indented differently.

Comment: look at print statements...